# Triangular Smoothing Formula Optimization

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm using a 5-point Triangle Moving Average:

$$S_j = (Y_{j-2} + 2Y_{j-1} + 3Y_j + 2Y_{j+1} + Y_{j+2}) / 9$$

The problem is that I often need to smooth my data more than once, and when I do this too much, it becomes noticeability very slow (and I'm using C++).

Is there a way to optimize this formula?

Like maybe skipping every other data point and then using interpolation in the end, or something clever?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "clever" way to improve the efficiency of the moving average filter is to implement it recursively; you will then need only two computations per data point, regardless of the length of the filter.

see page 281 and following of [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/tech_docs/dsp_book_Ch15.pdf).

(the algorithm given there is for a rectangular filter kernel, but the triangular kernel is just the rectangular filter applied twice)

Comment: My formula is weighted though (i.e. 1Y, 2Y, 3Y). So before I get too excited, can it even be recursive? If so, do you have any pdf references for creating and using "kernel" math. The pdf you gave is a wonderful tease, I really hope I can go down that path.

Comment: your weighted "triangular" average is equivalent to applying the uniform "rectangular" average twice.

Comment: I toyed with it and discovered that the real secret is using the rectangular formula with "more points". For instance, a 5-point rect is similar enough that running it twice is not needed for me. And a 7-point rect is similar to running my 5-point triangular twice. So, thank-you very much for the help. I'll toy with higher points and get it the way I want.

Comment: I found a problem with using more points: I do not know how to correctly fill-in the "missing data" into the beginning and end of the output array. Looking at the computer code on the last page 284 of your pdf, Y[0] to Y[49] and Y[4950] to Y[4999] are not calculated. PS...Line 290 should be: Y[I%] = ACC/101 per [link](http://www.dspguide.com/ch15/5.htm)